# Spread state with useState

Tags: reactjs

How can I spread an existing state with `useState`? (I need to concatenate the items)

```
const [inputValue, setInputValues] = React.useState('')

const handleSelectedItem = item=> {
    setInputValues(...inputValue, item) // That doesn't work
  }
```

For regular `setState` I would do something like:

```
this.setState(
        {...this.state,
          inputValue: item
        })
```

I have a dropdown of items, on select I need to append the selection to a textarea. That's why I need to concatenate a string.

Comment: if the datatype is a string and you want to concatenate you do that with a `+=`. `setInputValues(inputValue += item)`. If you are wanting to just set the new value then just pass `item` though

Comment: you don't need to spread anything if state is a primitive `setInputValues(item)`

Comment: @JohnRuddell, yes the datatype is a string but that won't work: _Cannot assign to 'inputValue' because it is a constant_

Comment: ok, so just use a template.```setInputValues(`${inputValue}${item}`)```

Comment: @user3378165 Why don't you do just `setInputValues(item) `. Do you need to concatenate with old selection? It looks like to me , that handler is for a dropdown, so no need the old value if I am right to assume it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, yes I do need to concatenate with old selection

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need to concatenate if its a string. Why not just the set item directly, or use an array if you want to use spread. Maybe I'm just strung up on the state being called inputValue :/

Comment: @user3378165 What kind of dom element this handler and state attached to?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Please see my edited question.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I do need to have the state as a string and not as an array

Comment: @user3378165 yes fine.. follow this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108016/spread-state-with-usestate#comment100735909_57108016)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To concatenate it you should just use a string template

```
const handleSelectedItem = item => {
  setInputValues(`${inputValue}${item}`)
}
```

another way to keep the data would be to store it in an array of words. Incase you needed to keep the words separate. If you were going to that would look like this

```
const [textareaValue, setTextareaValues] = React.useState([])

const handleSelectedItem = item => {
  setTextareaValues([...textareaValue, item]))
}
```

using it you could do something like

```
<textarea value={textareaValue.join('')}
```